# Move all files with same extension at once in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In terminal i could have used something like:

```
mv *.ext /some/output/dir/
```

I want to so the same in ruby. I can use system command for that under backticks (`) or using the system(), but how to achieve the same in ruby way?

I tried:

```
FileUtils.mv '*.sql', '/some/output/dir/'
```

This is not working as it looks specifically for a file name '*.sql'

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do:

```
FileUtils.mv Dir.glob('*.sql'), '/some/output/dir/'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a Glob, as in:

```
Dir.glob('*.sql').each do|f|
  # ... your logic here
end
```

or more succinct:

```
Dir.glob('*.sql').each {|f| FileUtils.mv(f, 'your/path/here')}
```

Check the official documentation on [FileUtils#mv](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-mv) which has even an example with Glob.

Update: If you want to be sure you don't iterate (although I wouldn't worry about it that much) you can always execute what you consider to be optimized in shell, directly from ruby, e.g.:

```
`mv *.ext /some/output/dir/`
```

Comment: thanks for your help. I am still not very optimistic about iterating over the whole list, moving them one at a time though.

Comment: My answer intended to introduce you to `glob`. I believe that by using a glob (even if you use it directly as BroiSatse suggested) you are going to iterate anyway.

Comment: Yeah i read about glob in details. Thanks a lot for introducing me to it. :)

Answer (score 1):

I will do using [`FileUtils::cp`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-cp), as it copies a file content `src` to `dest`. If `dest` is a directory, copies `src` to `dest/src`. If `src` is a list of files, then *dest* must be a **directory**.

```
FileUtils.cp Dir['*.sql'], '/some/output/dir/'
```

I wouldn't use [`::mv`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-mv), as *if file and dest exist on the different disk partition, the file is copied then the original file is removed.*

But if you don't bother with the deletion of the original files, then go with `::mv`.

Comment: Yeah i do actually need to move the file from one location to other so i'll be using ::mv itself. Rest the command works great. Thanks